# Newman-Penrose formalism and components of Weyl Riemann tensor

Tags: general-relativity

I am currently working through Chapter 1 on Chandrasekhar's book [Mathematical Theory of Black holes](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Mathematical_Theory_of_Black_Holes/LBOVcrzFfhsC?hl=en&gbpv=0) (where he lays out the Einstein equations in terms of the [Newman-Penrose formalism](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Spin-coefficient_formalism)). I am presently trying to relate components of the Riemann tensor to the Newman Penrose scalars using

\begin{equation}
R_{abcd}=W_{abcd}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\eta_{ac}R_{bd}-\eta_{bc}R_{ad}-\eta_{ad}R_{bc}+\eta_{bd}R_{ac}\right)-\frac{1}{6}\left(\eta_{ac}\eta_{bd}-\eta_{ad}\eta_{bc}\right)R
,
\end{equation}
where $R_{abcd}$ is the Riemann tensor, $W_{abcd}$ the Weyl tensor, $R_{ab}$ the Ricci tensor, and $R$ the Ricci scalar.

I use $\eta_{ab}$ above as the above equation is written in terms of the Newman-Penrose formalism, so that $\eta_{ab}$ is in fact the "tetrad metric" and equals 
\begin{equation}
\eta_{ab} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
(but the Riemann tensor, etc are *not* zero). The indices $a$, etc run over $1,2,3,4$. In his book (Eq. (293) in Chapter 1), Chandrasekhar (using the above two formulas) derives formulas such as
\begin{equation}
R_{1314}=\frac{1}{2}R_{11}
.
\end{equation}
(using arguments I won't get into here, he shows $C_{1314}=0$). The problem I have is: I get the opposite sign for all the Ricci tensor/scalar terms in my equations. For example I instead get
\begin{equation}
R_{1314}=-\frac{1}{2}R_{11}
,
\end{equation}
as $\eta_{34}=-1$. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong (and then give a correct derivation of the above equation), or if there is a series of typos in Chandrasekhar's book about the signs of the Ricci tensor/scalar terms?

Comment: What definition are you using for the Riemann tensor in terms of the Christoffel symbols and its derivatives? Is it the same as one that Chandrasekhar uses?

Comment: I follow all the definitions of Chandrasekhar for Christoffel symbols, etc.

Comment: Yes, on second thoughts I don't think the definition of the Riemann tensor is the issue. I consulted Chandrasekhar's book but I would need to look into it more to give a proper answer.

Comment: I checked the calculations for $R_{2324}$ and $R_{3132}$ and both my results obtained by substituting the results of equation 291 and the components of $\eta_{ab}$ on page 41 using equation 282 into equation 287 differ from the results in equation 293 by a multiplicative factor of -1. I have not attempted to check the other results in equation 293.

Comment: I just checked $R_{1212}$ and I got $R_{1212} = C_{1212} - R_{12} + R/6$ instead of the result $R_{1212} = C_{1212} + R_{12} - R/6$ that is stated in Chandrasekhar's book.

Comment: What I find strange is that I think Chandrasekhar needs the signs he states in his book in order to get his Eqs (310). Otherwise one gets the "wrong" sign for, e.g. \Phi_{00} in those identities.

Comment: What edition are you using? In one of the later editions Chandrashekar switched sign convention for part of the book, but not other parts.

Comment: I have the 2009 reprint of the 1992 edition. If one reads the last paragraph of the acknowledgements it seems to me that there are some outstanding misprints.

Comment: I have the 2000 reprint of the "Oxford Classics Series" version of the book (first issued by that published in 1998)

Comment: He does mention in the last paragraph of the acknowledgements of that addition (although that is dated 1985) that he found "many errors" but those seem to have stemmed from bold/light faced typesetting?

Answer (score 2):

After some digging around, I think the problem may lie in the definition of the Ricci tensor. In the original [Newman-Penrose article](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1962JMP.....3..566N/abstract), they cite [Eisenhart's book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Riemannian_Geometry/8h-TDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) on Riemannian geometry. There he defines

\begin{equation}
R_{ab}\equiv R^c{}_{abc}.
\end{equation}

So that the Weyl tensor is defined by
\begin{equation}
R_{abcd}=W_{abcd}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\eta_{ac}R_{bd}-\eta_{bc}R_{ad}-\eta_{ad}R_{bc}+\eta_{bd}R_{ac}\right)+\frac{1}{6}\left(\eta_{ac}\eta_{bd}-\eta_{ad}\eta_{bc}\right)R
\end{equation}
 which has the opposite sign for the Ricci tensor/scalar terms than what is presented in Chandrasekhar's book. Now while in my edition of [Chandrasekhar's book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Mathematical_Theory_of_Black_Holes/LBOVcrzFfhsC?hl=en&gbpv=0) he uses $R_{ab}=R^c{}_{acb}$, in an earlier edition (1983) that I dug out of the library it appears he may have originally used the other definition. Somehow maybe not everything was updated with that change.

As a bit of an aside, note then that if we use the definition

\begin{equation}
R_{ab}\equiv R^c{}_{acb},
\end{equation}

then to match the Eqs (4.2) in the Newman-Penrose article (and in Chandrasekhar's book) we need to define the Ricci "scalars" with the opposite sign than they do (note I am still working in $+---$ signature as they do); e.g.

\begin{equation}
\Phi_{00}=+\frac{1}{2}R_{11}
\end{equation}